# AppleScript close window on 'do shell hdiutil stdinpass' timeout

Tags: shell, terminal, applescript

Running 'do shell hdiutil create -encryption -stdinpass' pops up the "Enter disk image passphrase:" request as expected. If no entry is made I'd like to timeout and close the window.

The close command pops up a 'Do you want to close this window?' dialog, warning that the running process hdiutil will be terminated.

How should I terminate hdiutil so that the close window command can close that window with no running hdiutil processes? I don't want to terminate all hdiutil processes, just the one associated with that particular 'do shell'.

Alternatively, how could I unconditionally close the window, running processes or not?